# Have AuthenticationFailureHandler on REST Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to figure out what's the bean configuration for AuthenticationFailureHandler on a REST Login. The usually examples of the AuthenticationFailureHandler are coupled with Form-Login. What I'm trying to achieve is locked an account based on 3 incorrect login attempts. My current bean configuration

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"   authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="ROLE_USER"  />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"  />

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
<beans:bean id="restServicesSuccessHandler" class="com.cointraders.api.handlers.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />    

<beans:bean id="restServicesFailureHandler" class="com.cointraders.api.handlers.RestAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
```

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.cointraders.api.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


<beans:bean id="daoProvider" class="com.cointraders.api.daoauthproviders.CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>   

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="randomTokenGrant" />
</oauth:authorization-server>


<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="api" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
```

Comment: An `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is normally injected into an authentication filter. It's not really clear which kinds of authentication failure you want to deal with. The `BasicAuthenticationFilter` doesn't have that feature (and that's what you are using for authenticating clients). What is the requirement exactly?

Comment: @DaveSyer I am doing 3 factor authentication with the Custom Oauth Flow (using spring-oauth). When the user successfully authenticates they are issues an Access Token. If those attempts failed 3 times, I'll place a lock on their account (UserDetaislService->loadUserByUsername).

Comment: If you handle the authentication in a customized way can't you just manage it there?

Comment: @DaveSyer You're talking at the UserDetailsService level? I'm just looking to optimally leverage the Spring-Oauth/Spring Security stack.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you need then. OAuth(2 or other) is not a protocol for authentication. It's for issuing tokens that can be used to authenticate clients, which might be acting on behalf of a user. For used authentication you probably need Spring Security, but as I said, I'm not clear what you need yet.

Comment: @DaveSyer I've updated the code snippet above. What I am trying to achieve is an handler whenever there's an incorrect login; I log how many times it was done and if exceeded by 3, lock the account (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User->accountNonLocked set to false). I thought the handler would be the org.springframework.security.web.authentication.

Comment: @DaveSyer  AuthenticationFailureHandler but, this only works for Form Login. In my case, the login process is happening during the Oauth2 authentication process; The username, password and Client-Credential's issued access token is taken and then a new access token is re-issued. The Username and Password is placed in the request body and the Client Credentials token is passed in the header. The purpose for this is the ensure only authorized client used the login endpoint. So for this, I had to create a custom grant type (see authorization-server bean configuration above).